# jQplot line plot starts from x=0

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I would like to create a line plot for a vector of y values. In the default situation, x should starts from 1. I am wondering is there a way to let x values start from 0? 
Below is my code and [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JWhmQ/389/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var s= [12, 45, 89, 181, 111, 147, 116]            
        $.jqplot('chart1', [s], {
            seriesDefaults: { 
            showMarker:false,
            pointLabels: { show:false } ,
              },


            axes: {
                  xaxis: {
                    label :'Time units',
                    pad: 0,
                      },
                  yaxis: {
                    label: 'Number of individuals',
                    pad: 0
                      }
            },
             legend: {
                  show: true,
                  location: 'nw',
                  placement: 'inside',
                fontSize: '11px'
            } 
        })   
    })
```

​

Answer (score 1):

***Edit:*** it is also necessary to set the data of x.

Here is the ***[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JWhmQ/393/)***.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Maybe I did not express myself clearly. I would like to have the coordination of the first point is (0, 12), not (1, 12), the second is (1, 45), not (2, 45), the third...

Comment: @tao.hong Check my edited demo. You need to set the x value also.

Comment: I see your approach. Is there a way to offset values on the x axis without writing out all of the x values?

Answer (score 0):

In the first paragraph of [this link](http://www.jqplot.com/examples/line-charts.php) the author mentions that for what you are trying to achieve, you need an array of x,y data points (the ordered pairs themselves must be arrays too). So in your specific case this should give the desired effect:

```
var s= [[0, 12], [1, 45], [2, 89], [3, 181], [4, 111], [5, 147], [6, 116]];
```

For larger arrays of ordered pairs you can use a for loop to generate the ordered pair-arrays.